# Jenkins builds - parameterized maven goals

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

In Jenkins I have a "parameterized build".

I click "This build is parameterized".
 Then add "Choice parameter":

```
SELECT_TARGET=install -DskipTests=true
SELECT_TARGET=install
SELECT_TARGET=clean install
```

in Build option - Goals and options : ${SELECT_TARGET}

Then Build With parameter, it failed with

[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "${SELECT_TARGET}". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

In https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build.

> Open issues
>
> How can i pass the configured parameter to the maven execution of the
>   build? E.g. I've got a maven build and a specific profile should be
>   given as a String parameter in the Jenkins build.

How can I make it work?

Update :

I played with Jenkins plugins and settings, I think Jenkins has a miss-configuration.

How I made it work:

1. Use Extensible choice plugin
2. Remove "SELECT_TARGET="
3. use  $SELECT_TARGET as Pointed out in comment.

And it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try $SELECT_TARGET rather than ${SELECT_TARGET} and check.

Comment: Yes tried it that way

Comment: Please don't update the question with an answer, rather post it as an answer to your own question. Then please accept an answer so that the question is marked "solved"

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can simply

- tick the parameterized build flag
- create a choice named e.g. `SELECT_TARGET` with the values you want to choose from (the first one being the default)

```
install
install -DskipTests=true
clean install
```

- Use `$SELECT_TARGET` *(or which ever name you have chosen)* in your build goals.

There is no need for any plugins. Note that this works for every thing you want to configure - that's the target of parameterized builds